# Deleting Selected row in UITableview when Button click

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting an Exception while using `removeObjectAtIndex`.
I've searched in this forum but I haven't found the correct solution for this Exception. Actually, I'm getting the data from server when I click on button, I'm getting success and also I need to delete that row but the selected row is not deleting.

> My Exception:- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[**NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cfd1c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c46bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cfd1b9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cfca70e -[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:] + 94
>       4   SkigitApplication                   0x00000001097fab80 __20-[HomePage Confirm:]_block_invoke + 272
>       5   SkigitApplication                   0x00000001098c8628 __64-[AFHTTPRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke46 + 40
>       6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011160f186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>       7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011162e614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111616a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
>       9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf391f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9
>       10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cefadcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
>       11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cefa366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       12  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010db6da3e GSEventRunModal + 161
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010acf7900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       14  SkigitApplication                   0x00000001098c65bf main + 111
>       15  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111663145 start + 1
>       16  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my code: request is my array

```
In .h
NSMutableArray *request;

In .m


-(void)Confirm:(id)sender

{
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WebserviceUrl"];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];




[manager GET:test parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    if([[responseObject valueForKey:@"Success"]integerValue])
    {

        request=[[responseObject valueForKey:@"info"]mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"array=%@",request);
        frndcount=[[[request valueForKey:@"is_new"]objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"frndcount=%@",frndcount);
        notification_id= [[[request valueForKey:@"notification_id"]objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"notification_id=%@",notification_id);
        item_id= [[[request valueForKey:@"item_id"]objectAtIndex:0]mutableCopy];;
        NSLog(@"item_id=%@",item_id);
        frnd_count.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",frndcount];

        if (deleteIndexPath==0) {
           [request removeObjectAtIndex:deleteIndexPath.row];
            [self.msg_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        }



    }
}
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

Comment: can you show the complete exception.

Comment: Are you sure `request` is a mutable reference or array?

Comment: @AnushaK yup it is mutable reference

Comment: Can you show the code where you are creating this `mutable' array? Are you assigning any immutable array to this mutable array?

Comment: @AppDeveloper > You still not post the part of the code that you are setting a reference or initialising the request object.

Comment: @AppDeveloper > Are you sure the info data is an array? What's the output for `NSLog(@"array=%@",request);` ?

Comment: array=(
        {
        "date_notified" = "2015-03-25 21:01:01";
        "is_new" = 1;
        "item_id" = 1;
        "notification_id" = 503;
        "notification_message" = "You have friend request from admin";
        "user_id" = 1;
        "user_img" = "image URL";
        "user_img_thumb" = "image Thumb url";
    },
 this is my data

Comment: @AppDeveloper > Isn't it a dictionary?

Comment: No it's not dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78753/discussion-between-formiganinja-and-app-developer).

Answer (score 2):

Your `request` object is a `NSArray` object, that is immutable. you should change it to `NSMutableArray` and your problem is resolved.

**Update**

I don't know how you are initialising this object, but if you are doing something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *request = someData;
```

the referencing object may be not mutable, so you should resolve it doing this:

```
NSMutableArray *request = [someData mutableCopy];
```

Now, you have a mutable data.

Comment: No,it is NSMutableArray

Comment: The reference may be mutable but the instance it points to is certainly not

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not. Could you post your code where you are initialising the request object?

Comment: I'm getting data from web services and I'm using NSMutableArray for this to save the data in array